# How to call same method for different user using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

currently i am working on a chat application. so the scenario is : there will be a list of people displayed in the right side of the window. when I click on their name then a chat window will open with a unique id. so if i select 3 people then 3 chat window will appear. I have a function 'getData(int id)' which will call a ajax call to retrieve data from database using that id and it will automatically call each 5sec. now my question is how i will implement it? What i did so far is when i click on a user to chat with him i call the getData() to retrieve data for the previous conversation. at the same time when i select another person the same method will call and chat with previous person will be interrupted. Can anyone please suggest me how can i call same method for both person at the same time ?

Comment: You could handle each conversation separately by making "copies" of the handling methods. Alternatively, you could attach a `conversation_id` parameter to each request and hence use this parameter (to return as part of the response as well) to select the correct conversation. Besides that, you are checking the DB every 5 seconds... Assume now that you have few thousands users connected at the same time. Can you imagine what will happen to your DB?

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. yes you are right, I really need to think about the DB issue.